# How to change the border color of a button in libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

How to change the border color of a button. I know how to change the background, but I don’t know this, although I reviewed the entire documentation.
And is it possible to find out whether the button is pressed or not

Comment: Are you sure you checked the docs? https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html

Comment: Yes, I do not understand where these functions are.